# How to check version of ubuntu bootable USB

Tags: live-usb

I'm now on desktop Ubuntu 15.10 and I have some bootable USB drive. I'm pretty sure, that on the stick is installed another Ubuntu system, but I can't remember which version it is. Can I find it somewhere in files on this USB, or with some command?

I don't want to reboot only for this check.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its from `unetbootin`, then the lines at the end of `ubnfilel.txt` tells which version it installs.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is a stable answer, I was unable to find the ubuntu version in that file.

Answer (score 5):

If there is a folder `dists`, the name of the subfolder might help you to identify the version. For instance if there is `xenial` then the version is 16.04 -- see: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: I have the same question. That file ends with 
preseed/cli.seed
preseed/ltsp.seed
preseed/xubuntu.seed
I only use unetbootin, but possibly I was given this stick.

Comment: This helped me, I saw a focal folder in the dists folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The name of the subfolder under /dists is a good start.  Even better, look beyond the directory name as the directory itself may contain more specific information.  For example, if the release is xenial, then in /dists/xenial/Release you will find lines like: "Version: 16.04", "Description: Ubuntu Xenial 16.04", "Architectures: amd64 i386".  In this case, that probably came from the ISO file 
ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso rather than ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso or ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso, so it is out of date.  ubnfile1.txt (mentioned in another answer), on the other hand, wasn't terribly helpful.  It did not contain the "!6.04" anywhere but it did have xenial in a few paths, such as /dists/xenial/release

Answer (score 0):

If `ubnfilel.txt` doesn't work for you, here are two more files to check:

1. file `.disk/info`: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "Xenial Xerus" - Release amd64 (20160420.1)
2. file `README.diskdefines`, first line: #define DISKNAME  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "Xenial Xerus" - Release amd64
3. file `dists/<release name>/Release`, first 5 lines: Origin: Ubuntu Label: Ubuntu Suite: xenial Version: 16.04 Codename: xenial

The folders `.disk`, `dists` and the file `README.diskdefines` are to be found at the root of the USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

After I read some of the recomendations here, I did `grep -ri bionic` on the root folder of the USB.

I've found a folder .disk on my 18.04 live Kubuntu USB. There is a file named "info" inside which has the following text:

> Kubuntu 18.04.1 LTS "Bionic Beaver" - Release amd64 (20180725)

This is great because I wanted to know what is the specific "subversion" of the Ubuntu installation (I knew that it was 18.04 but didn't knew if I needed to upgrade it to 18.04.4).

I do not remember how I made this USB and do not know if this folder is present dependable on the method of creating the USB. So try it yourslef and see.